# What does 'range(y.shape[1])' mean in "for i in range(dataset2.shape[1]):"?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to find out how this above-mentioned piece of code works in a layman sense?
for context, this code contains **Numpy**, **Seaborn**, **Pandas** and **matplotlib**.

below is the line of code:

```
dataset2 = dataset.drop(columns = ['entry_id', 'pay_schedule', 'e_signed'])

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 12))
plt.suptitle('Histograms of Numerical Columns', fontsize=20)

**for i in range(dataset2.shape[1]):**

    plt.subplot(6, 3, i + 1)

    f = plt.gca()

    f.set_title(dataset2.columns.values[i])
```

Answer (score 1):

`pd.shape` will give you the number of `rows` and `columns` present in the dataFrame.

where, `df.shape[0]` will give you the `total rows` present in the dataFrame.

and, `df.shape[1]` will give you the number of `columns` present in the dataFrame.

**Example:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['10/2/2011', '11/2/2011', '12/2/2011'], 
                    'Phrases':['I have a cool family', 'I like avocados', 'I would like to go to school']})


df
Out[26]: 
        Date                       Phrases
0  10/2/2011          I have a cool family
1  11/2/2011               I like avocados
2  12/2/2011  I would like to go to school

df.shape
Out[27]: (3, 2)

df.shape[0]   #number of rows
Out[28]: 3

df.shape[1]   #number of columns
Out[29]: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

.shape returns a tuple (number of row, number of columns).  Therefore dataset.shape[1] is the number of columns.  i in range(dataset.shape[1]) simply iterates from 0 through the number of columns.